# Error creating new user account on ejabberd server from asmack android

Tags: android, amazon-ec2, ejabberd, asmack

I am trying to register a new user on ejabberd server from android asmack library but it gives me the following  error:

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$XMPPErrorException: XMPPError:
 forbidden - auth
```

I already made some change on ejabberd server please check if there is any mistake i made:

**{access, register, [{allow, all}]}.**

but i still getting same error.

```
{mod_register, [
                  %%
                  %% After successful registration, the user receives
                  %% a message with this subject and body.
                  %%
                  {welcome_message, {"Welcome!",
                                     "Welcome to a Jabber service powered by De$
                                     "For information about Jabber visit "
                                     "http://www.jabber.org"}},
                  %% Replace it with 'none' if you don't want to send such mess$
                  %%{welcome_message, none},

                  %%
                  %% When a user registers, send a notification to
                  %% these Jabber accounts.
                  %%
                  %%{registration_watchers, ["admin1@example.org"]},

                  {access_from, register}
                 ]},
```

Comment: please share mod_register module config details.

Comment: I update my question plz check know!!

Comment: please check if trusted_network in access rules are defined & set to allow + regiser to allow all. And please share the ejabberd server version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I also face same problem but after all i found solution. so add `mod_register` like

```
{access,mod_register, [{access_from, register}]},
```

in access rules on `ejabberd` server. may be it will help out.